# I couldn't inherit RecyclerView.Adapter<something.ViewHolder>()

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I had trouble inheriting RecyclerView to the class.
the problem occurs from ViewHolder. I already imported RecyclerView
but ViewHolder did not seem to work for me

the code below:

```
package love.partner.recyclerviewdemo.adapters

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class CustomAdapter(private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
}
```

Comment: You need to define your ``ViewHolder`` class *inside* ``CustomAdapter``, like the code here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter

Comment: Or you can define it outside and use a different name than ViewHolder to avoid confusion. It only needs to be defined inside if it's an `inner` class, and it only needs to be `inner` if it needs to access members of the adapter class.